# Possible to enable passwordless remote login without RSA keys?

Tags: automator, password, ssh

I have a very short term need on my own home network that nobody else has any access to whatsoever, to allow one mac to SSH into another and issue a restart command.  I want to script this so that it's just a doubleclick on an Automator workflow, and the remote machine restarts.  So far everything I have read online that claims to support this, has not worked.  Maybe I'm just doing something wrong but I'm stuck so looking for help.

I am totally aware of how unsecure this is, I just need this for a few days and I'm fine with all the security implications.  I don't want to have to set up keys to do proper passwordless access, and I don't want to have to install/compile anything new just for this.  I will most likely never need this capability again.  It's a very temporary and unusual need.

Running macOS Catalina on both machines.

Comment: Please read this, it might help you: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/470137/ssh-login-without-password-and-without-keys

Comment: Thanks but that question has only one answer, and it is to use keys.  I would like this to involve no changes to my machine whatsoever, no keys, no packages, nothing.  Just remotely restart the machine without altering it in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an **AppleScript** solution that may work for you.  This is the only way that I know that you can issue a command on the remote machine without having to set up ssh keys and such.

You will however, need to enable **Remote Apple Events** and **Remote Login** in the **Sharing** preferences on the remote machine.  You will also need to know the username and password, as well as its local IP address, to access the remote machine.

Since this process only allows targeting Applications that are already running on the remote machine... Since "Finder" is most likely running, we will tell it to open System Events.app file.  Then we can tell System Events.app to restart the computer.

*Note: I cannot test this on macOS Catalina because i'm on macOS Ventura.  I'm not sure if the path to System Events.app on Catalina will be the same.*

```
-- edit the username,password, and IP address

tell application "Finder" of machine "eppc://username:password@192.168.1.2" 
    open file "Macintosh HD:System:Library:CoreServices:System Events.app"
end tell

tell application "System Events" of machine "eppc://username:password@192.168.1.2"
    restart
end tell
```

If you have trouble compiling the above code... Try this

```
tell application "Finder" of machine (get "eppc://username:password@192.168.1.2") 
    using terms from application "Finder"
        open file "Macintosh HD:System:Library:CoreServices:System Events.app"
    end using terms from
end tell

tell application "System Events" of machine (get "eppc://username:password@192.168.1.2")
    using terms from application "System Events"
        restart
    end using terms from
end tell
```

After you test the code and make sure it works for you you can then add a Run AppleScript command to your Automator workflow with the code from above and you should be good to go.

Comment: This looks good, I will give it a spin, thank you!

Comment: It looks like this is going to work great!  Thanks so much... I'll sit with it for a bit and let you know if I find any problems, otherwise I'll accept the answer.  Much appreciated!

Comment: Honestly, before yesterday, I never before used AppleScript to connect to a remote machine and issue it commands.  I only figured out how to do it in an effort to help you.  I always just used Terminal to connect with my remote machines through SSH (which I have configured to connect without having to enter passwords or having to enter passwords for the `sudo` commands on those machines). I have 5 computers on my network so I created 1 AppleScript file with the code from my solution to target each computer to restart.  Then I created a Dictation Command "Mass Reboot" to run the script.  ;)

Comment: Yes!  That's exactly the sort of application this is perfect for.  My specific use case is to give my wife a simple "double click" solution to rebooting our dedicated media server, while I'm away for a few days on a rare business trip abroad.  Now she won't have to know anything about remote desktop, terminal, etc.  Just double click, and it's done.  This code is also quite flexible in issuing really ANY remote command.  Very handy, I suspect I will repurpose it well into the future... great work!

Answer (score 0):

Passwordless is not possible without providing keys or delegating to another form of authentication.

On the remote Mac:

- you will need an administrator account;
- Remote Login (`ssh`) must be enabled: System Preferences > Sharing > Remote Login

On the controlling Mac, you will need `expect` – or an alternative like [`empty`](https://empty.sourceforge.net).

I presumed `/usr/bin/expect` was installed by default but it appears not to be. Without one of these tools, I fear your goal is not trivially achievable.

### Shutdown

To restart your Mac from the command line use the command:

```
sudo shutdown now -r
```

See [Restart computers using Terminal on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/terminal/apd7d247a89-3560-4c3b-a471-3e66ff607040/mac) for more examples, included scheduled restarts.

### Expect

Use `expect` to issue a command remotely via `ssh`. As a single line, this will be something like:

```
expect -c 'spawn ssh username@192.168.1.2 ; expect "password:"; send "yourpassword\r"; sudo shutdown now -r'
```

You can write a multi-line `expect` script to reduce the number of likely typos and for testing.

See these guides:

- [ssh command with password in one line](https://vegastack.com/tutorials/use-ssh-command-with-password-in-single-line/).
- [ssh and expect](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/expect-script-ssh-example-tutorial)

### Shell Script

Consider writing a shell script to contain this command. This will be easier to call from an AppleScript or Automator workflow; a shell script will be testable, avoid escaping quotes, and escaping line endings.

### AppleScript/Automator

With this working, create an AppleScript using [do shell script](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2065/_index.html) or Automator workflow using the **Run Shell Script** step.

Comment: Yeah I tried expect, it's not on my machine and I don't want to install anything just for this.  Thanks though!

Comment: Sorry for presuming `expect` was installed by default. On my Mac it is available at `/usr/bin/expect` and not obviously part of any package manager. I have updated the answer.